# Is there any way to show number in letter format in php?

Tags: php, numbers, format

I am looking for the shortest way to get letter format from any number. I can do it with a lot of conditions if,elseif-s, but i need short way.

```
$mynumber=35566693;
$mynumber2=9444333;
echo some_format_function($mynumber).', ';
echo some_format_function($mynumber2);
//result should be something like ABBCCCDA, ABBBCCC
```

Update: Detailed explanation - Given number should be converted to letter format under these rules: 
1. First occured digit should be converted to A, second one to B, third one to C and so on. 2. Repeated digits should be converted to same letter(3453=>ABCA, not ABCD, not JKSJ)

Comment: You could make a lookup table, of an assoc array, and use array_walk or array_map to effectively 'translate' each number into a character.

Comment: What are the rules for converting a number to a letter?

Comment: What you mean by _"letter format"_?

Comment: Without you telling us what the rules are for the conversion this question in not answerable

Comment: i have given 2 examples in sample code. No any another conditions. I just need number to letter.

Comment: PeeHaa, detailed explanation: Given number should be converted to letter format under these rules: 1. First occured digit should be converted to A, second one to B, third one to C and so on. 2. Repeated digits should be converted to same letter(3453=>ABCA not ABCD)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an attempt to be the first to actually *read* your question before answering, try this:

```
function num_to_letter($num) {
    $map = array();
    $letters = str_split("ABCDEFGHIJ"); // ten characters
    return preg_replace_callback("/\d/",function($n) use (&$map,&$letters) {
        $digit = $n[0];
        if( !isset($map[$digit])) $map[$digit] = array_shift($letters);
        return $map[$digit];
    },$num);
}
```

Usage:

```
echo num_to_letter(3556693); // ABBCCDA
```

For longer numbers, pass them as strings:

```
echo num_to_letters("1123124648976127846187243232234");
                  // AABCABDEDFGHEABHFDEAFHBDCBCBBCD
```

Comment: it seems, this one is more universal solution, thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
str_replace(
  [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 
  ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'],
  $mynumber
);
```

Should do the trick.

**UPD** For native order of letters:

```
$a=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]; // stub subst array
$l=chr(ord('A')-1);       // first letter
foreach(str_split($mynumber) as $sym) { 
  if(is_int($a[$sym]))    // first meet 
    $a[$sym] = $l = chr(ord($l)+1); 
}
str_replace(              // let’s go
  [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 
  $a,
  $mynumber
);
```

Comment: this simple method has one problem, but "A" should occur first, then B, then C etc.

Comment: Oups. Didn’t realize. Please see upd.

Answer (score 0):

As you explained it, what you want is such function:

```
<?php
$mynumber=35566693;
$mynumber2=9444333;
$mynumber3=3453;
echo some_format_function($mynumber).', ';
echo some_format_function($mynumber2).', ';
echo some_format_function($mynumber3);

 function some_format_function ($int) {
     $out = '';

     $use = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J');


     $usedIndex = -1;     

     $mappings = array();

     for ($x =0; $x<strlen($int);++$x) {

         $curChar = substr($int,$x,1);

         if (!isset($mappings[$curChar])) {
            ++$usedIndex;
            $mappings[$curChar]  = $use[$usedIndex];                
         }

         $out .= $mappings[$curChar];


     }
     return $out;
 }
```

Comment: Does NOT perform as requested. Try `$mynumber=123456789;` and I'm fairly sure you won't get what was asked for...

Comment: Yes, I've notices that. I'll try to find solution

Comment: Niet the Dark Absol, may be you are right, i havent tested such numbers you gave, but in my current special case 4 different letters are enough, and it work for them, thats why i choosed the answer as a solution.

Comment: @Elvin85 I can tell you from experience that it's better to have a solution that works properly. Try testing with `12344321` - you'll get `ABCDDABC`, not `ABCDDCBA` ;)

Comment: @Elvin85 I've just updated it. Now it is working. You should always explain in details what you want at the beginning